# SQL Server 2000 Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2000

I have a challenge with replication on SQL Server 2000. The replication has full permissions, but still I get this below error. The SQL Server 2000 is installed on the C: Drive, but the database is on E:.

> \myserver\Replication\unc\myserver_GS_ECC25_2675_Publication1\20130813090100\SpInsertSbraConf_1469.sch'
>   could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: Merge Replication
>   Provider (Agent); Error number: -2147201001)
>
> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match
>   table definition. (Source: myserver (Data source); Error number: 213)

Answer (score 1):

That error would imply to me that there is a table layout difference between the publisher and the subscriber. Have any recent updates to the DB structure been applied to one but not the other?

You could run a DB comparison tool (something like the free edition of http://www.sqleffects.com/Articles/Product/sqlAccordInfo/aboutSqlAccordCommunityEd.html should be more than sufficient) against the two databases to check for this.

You probably shouldn't be using SQL 2000 any more - it is somewhat old and the extended support period for its last release (SP4) ended in April this year.

Comment: Thanks David. The subscriber is an empty databse, so I am trying to send the snapshot of the publisher to the subscriber first, so I am not sure what table the application is talking about. Yes, it is only sql 2000 that works with that software, and the manufacturer has no alternative to produce diffrent databse for the software.

Comment: I would not pay for software that only works on something that old. It would not fill me with confidence in the rest of the product!

Comment: yes, you are right. But is from aircraft manifacturer and could not work with other database, so they stick to this sql 2000. I hope I can sort this out, but I will keep in up to date wht you may help me to do. The tables in each database is almost 200 and the store procedures are almost 2000, so i really just do not know which table to start working on. I will look at the link to the  aforementioned software you sent. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you run the suggested tool or one like it, it will compare all the objects in each database and tell you if any differ (or are missing in one of the two places).

Comment: Yes, I will try the tool expecting them to send it it my email which is the community edition Cheers.

Comment: David, I have downloaded the application but when I was trying to compare them it says permission denied. Which one should I compared. I was using .mdf file. Pls let nme know what permission issue that is causing this.

Comment: You might need to ask the developers that. I assume it needs fairly high permissions though (probably "view server state" at least) in order to be able to read the DB structure. It is not designed to compare mdf files directly: you need to give it logins to each database and it collects information via the system management views/functions.

Comment: David, when I published only the tables,  the merge replication works. I really need to get this working. Is there any implication if stored procedures are not published? The subscribers will be like back up. Or any script that can group the stored procedures and do something easier for this replication to work fully. The stored procedures are 2000, if i remove one not to be publish another one will pop can not propagate to the subscriber. Thanks for your resposne so far.

Comment: "I really need to get this working" - as your supplier is forcing you to hold back on an unsupported version you probably need to ask them for support. I'm not exactly a domain expert on replication, particularly back as far as MSSQL2000.

Comment: Hi David, I was able to get all the stored procedure that create this error " column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition". The total number of the stored procedures are 35 out of the 900 stored procedures. When I unchecked them, the replication works fine. I want to ask you can this have effect on my publication.